# Elliptical orbits passing 2 points

Tags: orbital-motion

I would like to find **set of possible elliptical orbits which pass 2 points in plane**. I was searching for some solutions in orbital mechanics texts but I didn't found any.

There are several possible approaches but I'm not sure which is the best - both looks quite difficult to solve algebraically.

1. using **polar equation relative to focus** with $(R_1,\phi_1),(R_2,\phi_2)$, being coordinates of points
   $$ R_1 = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-ecos(\phi_1-\theta)} $$
   $$ R_2 = \frac{a(1-e^2)}{1-ecos(\phi_2-\theta)} $$
   then for given $\theta$ solve for semimajor axis $a$ and eccentricity $e$
2. using deffinition of elipse as a **set of points of the same distance from both foci**. Given 2 points of cartesian coordinates $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ and one focus in origin $(0,0)$. For each given distance parameter $L$ solve for coordinates of second focus $(x_f,y_f)$,
   $$ L = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_2^2} + \sqrt{(x_1 - x_f)^2 + (y_1 - y_f)^2} $$
   $$ L = \sqrt{x_2^2 + y_2^2} + \sqrt{(x_2 - x_f)^2 + (y_2 - y_f)^2} $$
3. I can also first rotate the coordinate system (or my input points) by given angle (which is my arbitrary parameter) and then use some simplified equation of **ellipse which has major axis parallel to x-axis** which has just 2 degrees of freedom. But even after this rotation I don't see much simplification of algebraic solution.

---

Nevertheless, the resulting equations are difficult to solve.I solved it using sympy, but the solution is very long expressing hard to simplyfy. I would like some more elegant solution if there is any.

I would also like to implement this into computer as a part of orbital transfer optimization, so I would prefer some explicit expression which is fast to evaluate numerically ( for example goniometric functions are quite slow to evaluate )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about pure math (finding the solutions, try http://math.stackexchange.com), symbolic manipulation (simplifying the solutions, try http://mathematica.stackexchange.com, or http://stackoverflow.com/ for a different language), and numerical efficiency (coding the solutions, try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com), but not physics.

Comment: OK, but I expect that this should be quite common problem of orbital mechanics, that is why I ask in physics. Nevertheless, I would try also math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure if there is an explicit equation, but I do remember that a by the community made mod for the game Kerbal Space Program, called [MechJeb](http://mechjeb.com/), this is calculated by solving a [Lambert's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem). The code they used to calculate this can be found on [github](https://github.com/MuMech/MechJeb2/blob/master/MechJeb2/LambertSolver.cs).

Someone else also made a [web application](http://alexmoon.github.io/ksp/) which can calculate [Porkchop plots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porkchop_plot) and its code can also be found on [github](https://github.com/alexmoon/ksp).

Both calculate the solution by constraining the time between the two given points rather than your $\theta$. So this might be the cause the need for a numerical solver, rather than a explicit equation.

Comment: Thank you very much! all your links are very usefull. What's more - reading about the Lambert's problem I found this great python package called [Keplerian Toolbox](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keptoolbox/) which can solve the orbital transfer problems which I wonted to develop by myself. Instead of reinventing the wheel I should reather try to understand source code of this package.